# Read a line when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jbutton, bufferedreader

I have to do a quiz class that will read the questions from a text file, I am stuck trying to make the program work in such way that every time the answer button is pressed it reads the next question (line in the text file), I tried many suggestions from the internet but the furthest i got was to read the first line when the program runs then using `String[] args = new String[0];`  to have a new frame when the button is pressed but then the text wouldn't read at all.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pan1;
    static JButton boutonRetour,boutonEnregistrer;
    static JTextField reponse,question;
    static int counter1 = 1;
    static int lines=0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

        frame.setSize(700,600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        question=new JTextField(10);
        question.setBounds(150, 220, 450, 50); 
        question.setEditable(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(null, 0, 0, 700, 600, this);
            }
        });

        boutonEnregistrer=new JButton("Answer");
        boutonEnregistrer.setBounds(0,513,100,50);

        boutonEnregistrer.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 182));
        boutonEnregistrer.setForeground(Color.white);
        boutonEnregistrer.setFocusPainted(false);
        boutonEnregistrer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));

        boutonEnregistrer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                counter1++;  
                String[] args = new String[0];              

                main(args); 
                /*
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
                frame.removeAll();
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
                */   
            } 
        });


        frame.add(question);        
        frame.add(boutonEnregistrer);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        System.out.println(counter1);


        try {        
            BufferedReader br =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Questions.txt"));
            String word = null;
            while((word =br.readLine()) != null) {
                lines++;
            if (lines == counter1){
                question.setText(word);
                break;
```

}

```
            }

        } catch(IOException err) {

        }                          
        frame.validate();
        System.out.println(lines);

    };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the text wouldn't read at all? Also you should print the stack trace (err.printStackTrace()) in the catch block so that you would atleast know there was an error.

Comment: the first time the program runs it works,it reads the first line and display it on the jtextfield, but when i press the button a new frame open but without any text displayed on the textfield...i added the err.printStackTrace() but there is no error just not working the way i need it to

Comment: Try closing your BufferedReaders. Call `br.close()` in a finally block. Problem may occur because the second instance of the BufferedReader may be waiting on the first stream to close.

Comment: What do you use to compile your program? You have syntax errors in your code (unmatched `*/`). Could it be the class file isn't updated?

Comment: i added a finally block with br.close(); on it i have a cannot find symbol, i also tried putting it just after the while loop but it didn't change anything...i use netbeans on my program the matching /* is just before the SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); line, must've deleted it while editing the post

Answer (score 0):

You use the `lines` variable to keep track of the last line that was read. However that is not happening in your code. The while loop always runs until the reader reaches EOF.

You should break from the loop once you read the desired line:

```
if (lines == counter1){
    question.setText(word);
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! now the jtextfield isn't empty anymore...but it always displays the same line (the first one) even tho the counter and lines number is at 5 or 20

Comment: The code that you edited your Question with isn't correct. You need the `break;` statement to be in the if block. Currently it is not and it is breaking after one iteration of the loop.